# How do I have desktop always display favorites bar (Ubuntu Dock) on left?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, favorites

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2. I use a TV thru HDMI and the adjustment for TV.  It looks great.

When I start in they AM there is usually the favorites bar on the left that displays my favorite programs.  After a few times when the computer has gone into sleep mode (or whatever that is called) and I log back in, the bar on the left is gone and I have to hit  "*Activities*" at the top for it to show up.

I would like it to always be there.  I went into "display" settings and the "Auto-hide the Dock" is off.  That seems to be the only thing that sounds like it should apply.

Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: If you're using Ubuntu, you should tell us your release. The mention of activities makes me think of gnome, but are you using Vanilla-GNOME or standard Ubuntu-GNOME  (your release of Ubuntu could be a huge start, plus letting us know if you've added any extensions which change behavior)

Comment: Very sorry about that.  Ubuntu 18.04.2.  I don't think I've added extensions, just let it update a few times and added some programs like a video player and things like that.

Answer (score 2):

The always visible "*favourites bar*" is provided by the GNOME shell extension Ubuntu Dock (package name: `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`). As per GNOME's security policy, whenever your system is suspended (goes to sleep), all the extensions get disabled automatically until you get back in, and then the extensions get re-enabled. Somehow it's failing here for the Ubuntu dock extension in your case.

As a temporary workaround either restart your system (or log out and log in again) or simply restart GNOME shell by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing `r`, and finally hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This works great.  Thank you.

Comment: @PSimdars If you find this answer useful, you may consider ["accepting" it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers) (by clicking the tick (✓) next to it) to indicate you've found a working solution and also so that others may more easily find it in the future.